# Unable to point external tables created using hive from spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have created external table in hive and I am able to see the tables and records from hive shell. But, when I am trying to point the same database from spark-shell by mentioning the path, I am only getting the default database in spark, but not able to see the databases and tables that I were created .

I have checked the path also through the following command
`spark2.conf.get("spark.sql.warehouse.dir")`, it is giving the same location that I have specified. 
I don't have permission issues also.

Comment: Provide your code what ever you tried

Answer (score -1):

1.Check your `hive-site.xml` is correct in spark conf directory;

2.`SparkSession.enableHiveSupport()` make your sparkSession support hive.